# bash time output processing

Tags: bash, time, io

I know that `time` will send timing statistics output to `stderr`. But somehow I couldn't capture it either in a bash script or into a file via redirection:

```
time $cmd 1>/dev/null 2>file
$output=`cat file`
```

Or

```
$output=`time $cmd 1>/dev/null`
```

I'm only interested in timing, not the direct output of the command. I've read some posts overhere but still no luck finding a viable solution. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
(time $cmd) 1>/dev/null 2>file
```

so that `(time $cmd)` is executed in a subshell environment and you can then redirect its output.

Comment: Better to say `(time $cmd 2>/dev/null 1>&2) 2>captured` so that stderr from the command gets thrown away, too.

Answer (score 3):

(Using GNU time `/usr/bin/time` rather than bash builtin) (Thanks @Michael Krelin)
(Or invoke as `\time`) (Thanks @Sorpigal, if I ever knew this I'd entirely forgotten)

How about using the `-o` and maybe `-a` command line options:

```
-o FILE, --output=FILE
      Do not send the results to stderr, but overwrite the specified file.

-a, --append
      (Used together with -o.) Do not overwrite but append.
```

Comment: Upvoted both, but I'd add to your answer that you need to use either full path to time binary or `"time"` quoted to make it use executable and not bash builtin.

Comment: +1, but note that you can just say `\time` to invoke the executable version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to bench optimizations. The idea was to run the program several times then output statistics on run durations.

I used the following command lines:

*1st run:* `(time ./myprog)2>times.log`

*Next runs:* `(time ./myprog)2>>times.log`

Note that my (bash?) built-in `time` outputs statistics in the form:

```
    real    0m2.548s
    user    0m7.341s
    sys     0m0.007s
```

Then I ran the following Perl script to retrieve statistics:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

    open FH, './times.log' or die "ERROR: ", $!;

    my $useracc1 = 0;
    my $useracc2 = 0;
    my $usermean = 0;
    my $uservar = 0;
    my $temp = 0;

    while(<FH>)
    {
        if("$_" =~ /user/)
        {
            if("$_" =~ /(\d+)m(\d{1,2})\.(\d{3})s/)
            {
                $usercpt++;
                $temp = $1*60 + $2 + $3*0.001;
                $useracc1 += $temp;
                $useracc2 += $temp**2;
            }
        }
    }

    if($usercpt ne 0)
    {
        $usermean = $useracc1 / $usercpt;
        $userdev = sqrt($useracc2 / $usercpt - $usermean**2);
        $usermean = int($usermean*1000)/1000;
        $userdev = int($userdev*1000)/1000;
    }
    else
    {
        $usermean = "---";
        $userdev = "---";
    }

    print "User: ", $usercpt, " runs, avg. ", $usermean, "s, std.dev. ", $userdev,"s\n";
```

Of course, regular expressions may require adjustements depending on your `time` output format. It can also be easily extended to include real and system statistics.