# bash redirect stderr for time command?

Tags: bash, time

An application with stderr is being run using the time command.  I want the output of the application to be redirected to /dev/null, the stderr redirected to a log, and the timing redirected to a log.

executing the command:

```
time cmd args >/dev/null 2>log
```

redirects the cmd, but not the time command with the timings.

Comment: A search on SO for '`[bash] time output`' shows many plausible duplicates, including [`time` output redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434522/time-output-redirection), [Bash `time` output processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308400/bash-time-output-processing) (the oldest of these three), and [Is there a way to redirect `time` output to file in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356628/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-time-output-to-file-in-linux).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Any particular reason you are not nominating to close as a duplicate of one of them?

Comment: Also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032 and [perhaps more duplicates](https://www.google.com/search?q=http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @tripleee: mainly that I am not convinced I've got a canonical duplicate.  The answer for the earliest one of the three I list is not very good.  There are probably other better duplicates out there.  I need to look at what you found too.  I live in hope someone else will do the hard work of finding a really good duplicate.  As a wielder of Mjölnir, I have to be very careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to capture the `time` output to the log file, then use:

```
{ time seq 1000 >/dev/null; } 2>log
```

Comment: Excellent use of curly braces to redirect output from a code block. If you want to know more about curly braces, then check out http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#CODEBLOCKREF