# How to redirect two output of two different commands in Linux to separate file?

Tags: bash, curl

The result of `curl -s http://127.0.0.1` is `200 OK`

The result of `/usr/bin/time -f "%e" curl -s http://127.0.0.1` is `200 OK0.08`

In this case, I only need `0.08`. How can I only get `0.08` instead of the whole string when I redirect the output to `>> result.txt`?

ps: the response can change in the future (not always `200 OK`), and the format of time can also change in the future. So I really need a solution that is not based on string manipulation. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your `/usr/bin/time` writes to stdout?  You're saying if you do `/usr/bin/time ls > /dev/null` it doesn't print anything at all?  I would have expected it to write to stderr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash redirect stderr for time command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322479/bash-redirect-stderr-for-time-command)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
/usr/bin/time -f "%e" curl -s -o /dev/null http://127.0.0.1
```

By adding `-o /dev/null` you are telling `curl` to write its output nowhere, leaving you with only the output of `time`.